# SlidingDrawer get's behind Admob ad

Tags: android, admob, slidingdrawer

I have a framelayout(my main layout), im drawing ads on it.

```
 AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "id");

 FrameLayout v = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.framemain);
 v.addView(adView);
 AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
 request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
 request.addTestDevice("41A48DB6B62384BDC3BEE5929AEC18DF");
 adView.loadAd(request);
```

The problem is, that when dragging sliding drawer, part of it remains behind the ad. Any way to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recently added view is at the top of the z-order. So if you add this ad view last, it will be drawn at the top.

Comment: i am adding sliding drawer throught xml so i don't really know how to add it earlier than admob.

Comment: just found i can add admob in xml

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the weight of the sliding drawer to greater than the AdView. That should fix it.